# PostgreSQL : enforce ssl

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I have configured PostgreSQL DB server to use SSL. My JBoss datasource is also configured to communicate over SSL. Everything works fine.

However When a user tries to connect using pgAdmin, it is possible to connect without making any SSL configuration changes in pgadmin. Does it mean that the postgres db server is still accepting non-ssl connections ?

If no, what can be a valid justification for pgadmin being able to communicate with a SSL enabled postgresql.

If yes, how can we enforce that the db server accepts only ssl connections.

Note : I am using one-way ssl (no client certificates) and I did make sure that all pg_hba.conf entries are using "hostssl" (not "host").

Answer (score 0):

Chances are PgAdmin is set to use the ssl mode of "prefer" (in other words, use ssl if available). This is usually the default with libpq applications including pgAdmin.

So first thing to check is to verify what your settings are.  You can test by fiddling with your ssl options.

Finally make sure you are connecting over a network connection.  hostssl doesn't apply to unix domain sockets.